# how to change spacing between characters of a .ttf-Font in python?

Tags: python, fonts, spacing, truetype

I'm creating a text-generator for OCR applications and want to vary the spacing between the characters of my .ttf-Font (say, like `np.random.uniform(0.2,1.2)*default_spacing` - **not** just change the default spacing of the font via e.g. FontForge).

This generator (https://github.com/Belval/TextRecognitionDataGenerator) has a nice way of allowing different spacings between words, but I need to vary the spacing between **characters**!

How can this be done? Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have jpg-images for each letter? Why does `np.random.uniform(0.2,1.2)*default_spacing` not work?

Comment: How would I even address `default_spacing` ? `print()` doesn't have any options for that, afaik. I do have .jgp images for each character, but I don't see how that's of any help as I explicitly try to work with the provided .ttf-Font.

Comment: You create the images for each letter, bitmap or numpy array. Then you insert them into a larger array at a certain offset. The offset is determined by your default_spacing.